# How to connect jenkins to docker?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-docker

I have one jenkins server. There I cannot install docker. So the question is what is the correct way of integrating jenkins with a docker server? Whats the fastest easiest and most convenient way to integrate it?

1.Through a jenkins node with docker installed there

2.Through ssh? And if - how would the configuration look?

3.Only through installed docker on the main jenkins server

4.Other?

Comment: Option 1 is feasible and easy too, check the Jenkins [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin)

Comment: On a Jenkins Server, you have to install Docker engine as it is required. Moreover, you have to install Docker engine on Jenkins Slave if you want to build Docker images, deploy to test environment etc.

Jenkins plugins will help you to create easy pipelines such as `dockerPush`, adding private Docker registry (AWS ECR, Azure ACR etc) credentials and others.

Answer (score 1):

that depends on the version of Docker engine you are about to install and the jobs you want to sue it for ( pipeline , freestyle )

basically if your docker engine is no greater then version 1.11 the best way is to use Docker Plugin from Jenkins if you want to simulate containers as slaves.

you can also use workflow docker plugin and even ssh as you said.

it all depends on what you want to achieve from your docker usage